# How to get the current rounded hour in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

`select current_time()` gives:

```
16:43:16
```

how can I modify it to get:

```
16:00
```

I tried to play with it a bit and I wrote this:

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,CURDATE(),current_timestamp())
```

Which gives:

```
16
```

I can convert it to string and add `:00` but I think there might be easier way to get what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: would [date_format](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) sort you, @Luis?

Comment: So, you're not rounding it right? Rounding 16:43 would yield 17.

Comment: @MarcusAdams  I think OP meant "rounded down".  To get some values rounded "up" (time value with minutes :30:00 or greater) and other values rounded down, we could use a `+ INTERVAL 30 MINUTES` trick before truncating. (We'd also need to clarify the spec, what to return for `23:45`, should we return `00:00` or `24:00` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd use `DATE_FORMAT` with appropriate format including literals e.g.

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT( CURRENT_TIME() ,'%H:00')
```

MySQL also provides equivalent `TIME_FORMAT` function

```
 SELECT TIME_FORMAT( CURRENT_TIME() ,'%H:00')
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format